# Google Looker Studio: is there is a way to display scorecard with calculated "Top-#" item by points?

Tags: dashboard, looker-studio

I have:

**1. [Table in Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WHFmMjfAm0P96j5ay_dAq4J65D7bd4ILv46ER6f6SJM/edit#gid=0) with some data, e.g.:**

| Item Name | Points |
| --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 100 |
| Item 23 | 200 **(this is the target)** |
| Item 12 | 150 |

**2. [Dashboard](https://lookerstudio.google.com/reporting/1aa5e5dc-15f5-47c0-923a-fd4909a5f162) that should display such scorecards:**

---

[image: example]

---

**Goal:**

1. To display a top X item in the scorecard
2. Without modifying source table
3. In the real world it will use Data Ranges as well

**Links:**

1. [Dashboard](https://lookerstudio.google.com/reporting/1aa5e5dc-15f5-47c0-923a-fd4909a5f162)
2. [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WHFmMjfAm0P96j5ay_dAq4J65D7bd4ILv46ER6f6SJM/edit#gid=0)

I manage to solve this via custom connector & Google Apps Script, but in this case I loose possibility to manage the calculation from the dashboard (and refresh time for custom connector is 12h VS default 15min for Google Sheets).

Maybe someone has better decision? Thanks in advance.

**UPD 1:**

1. My Community Connector refresh rate screen:
   [image: My Community Connector refresh rate]
2. [Some documentation about it](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7020039#see-data-refresh-rates-by-connector&zippy=%2Cin-this-article%2Cdata-refresh-rates-by-connector)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is display the top-3 rankings in scorecards, correct?

From the report edit view, you can create new fields in your datasource to extract those values. There will still be a refresh time of 12h for the data incoming from Google Sheets, but that can be set to 15min as well.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, as the core of the the question is skipped by the sentence "*From the report edit view, you can create new fields in your datasource to extract those values*" - Could you elaborate on that section? Also, the information on the default Google Sheets Refresh rate is incorrect as stated in the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7020039) (as well as the question) - it's 15 minutes.

Comment: Thank you, @paradise, for you time.

Let me clarify some details:
1. Almost correct: I want to be able to display any one top-X in my scorecard.

2. About "create new fields": This is the question. I don't understand how can I calculate the "rating place" on the fly. If you could provide some examples or thought about it - it would be great.

3. About **15min** update:
As I mentioned in my question: I used to build community connector for that, which refresh time is 12h only.
I added an image to my post with it. But this is not the question, the question is how to calculate it.

Comment: Thanks, @Nimantham you're right about the main question.
About refresh rate: I answered above about Community Connector & add a pic for it. But this is not important.